# Issue linking Ranorex CodedUI tests to MTM/VSO 2013 CI following recent VSO update

Tags: visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, azure-devops, mtm, ranorex

We have an established CI process which links 118 Ranorex test cases to MTM test cases and runs them on a dedicated automation VM, which is triggered by a timed build in Visual Studio.

The CI process is still working correctly, but I have just tried to add another test and found that due to changes in the layout of the test case work item page in VSO/MTM, the 'Associated Automation' function is no longer shown.

So you used to click on the ellipses and the list of test cases to be linked would appear: [VS CodedUI MTM_VSO work item linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnr58.png)

As you can see in this image, the 'Associated Automation' tab has moved and the linking mechanism is no longer present: [Missing MTM_VSO test case mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkjw.png)

I think it is tied into this recent Microsoft VSO update hxxps://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-dec-10-vso (sorry for posting the link this way but I can't have more than 2 links) but I wondered if anyone else had encountered this issue and how to resolve it.

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to make everything clear.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a feedback submitted for this on Visual Studio page, refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2137069

Currently, you can create the test case from your test assemblies via following steps first and then update the test cases.

1. Run "Developer Command Prompt" and navigate to the debug folder via "cd" command. For example: `cd C:\xxx\xxx\solution\testproject\bin\debug`
2. Create test case for the test assemblies via "tcm testcase" command: `tcm testcase /collection:https:xxxxx/DefaultCollection /teamproject:yourproject /import /storage:xxx.dll`

Comment: HI Eddie, thanks for your reply. I will investigate your suggested solution. There is another report of it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a09c3ac-168b-40ff-99f3-87955cf7e6ca/associated-automation-test-case-screen-is-blank?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: @JimLin According to the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400658/why-cant-i-can-use-anymore-the-test-automation-feature-with-vso?noredirect=1#comment56566357_34400658, this issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: MS have now fixed the issue and applied a hot fix.

From MS:
We are working on servicing steps to update the cache, but if the issue is not resolved yet you can use one of these workarounds 1. Delete the local cache at C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{version} (make sure all instances of VS are closed) 2. Create a new field in any work item type using the admin process page After doing 1 or 2 hit refresh in VS and create a new test case