# Associate Automation Add button missing with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, automated-tests, azure-devops

I am not able to add associated automations in visual studio 2013 like the tutorials tell me to. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)

My screen when I query for a testcase is slightly different and does not have a button for me to add associated automations.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check connecting to VSO, and I could reproduce your issue. So I assume you are using VSO, correct?

There is already a feedback submitted for this issue on Visual Studio page, refer to this link for details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2137069

Similar case: [Issue linking Ranorex CodedUI tests to MTM/VSO 2013 CI following recent VSO update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360659/issue-linking-ranorex-codedui-tests-to-mtm-vso-2013-ci-following-recent-vso-upda)