# Why can't I can use anymore the Test Automation feature with VSO

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

So basically, I'm using Visual Studio Online for some months, and I've a lot of existing test cases, each being associated with a unit test thanks to the Test Automation feature.

Since a few days, I cannot anymore associate test automation to my test cases. Might be related to the changes that have been introduced with the December 10th update: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/2015-dec-10-vso

Basically, **all existing and new test cases now show an empty screen instead of the UI that allows me to specify which unit test is associated with the test case**. Here's an screenshot from VS 2013:

[image]

Displaying the same UI from Test Manager also shows an empty UI:

[image]

The only way to display the fields associated to the test automation is now to use VSO:

[image]

The problem is, those fields are read only.

I've managed to modify my SCRUM process to slightly alter the Test Case work item type UI:

[image]

So now those fields are displayed here:

[image]

Those fields are *not* read only, but I do not have anymore the UI that allows to automatically fill them by choosing one of the unit test within the VS Solution.

**So basically the question is: what's wrong with VSO, how can I use test automation again? Is this a bug/regression?**

Similar (unanswered) question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a09c3ac-168b-40ff-99f3-87955cf7e6ca/associated-automation-test-case-screen-is-blank?forum=TFService

Comment: The same with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360659/issue-linking-ranorex-codedui-tests-to-mtm-vso-2013-ci-following-recent-vso-upda

Comment: @Eddie I wasn't able to find the other question, looks like it's really a regression of VSO... I'll try the suggestion you provided. Hopefully they'll fix this ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that we introduced recently. We have a fix for it, and we will hotfix the service today or tomorrow.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What do we have to do to see it now?  Update?  Restart computer or Visual Studio?

Comment: We are working on servicing steps to update the cache, but if the issue is not resolved yet you can use one of these workarounds

1. Delete the local cache at C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{version} (make sure all instances of VS are closed)
2. Create a new field in any work item type using the admin process page
 
After doing 1 or 2 hit refresh in VS and create a new test case.